# JavaScript Google Maps API and web application on IPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have developed a web application for mobile phones that uses JavaScript Google API. It works fine on any Android phone however on IPhone the map is not "dragable" - I can't move the map (I click on a map and try to move it but it stays the same as if I was trying to move a static image). I found some information pointing out that it is a bug on the IPhone side. If it is true - is there any workaround?

The application that I developed is used as a web application using JavaScript Google Maps API V3, not the IPhone application.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using click or touch events?
The iPhone won't see clicks.

Comment: I'm using Google Maps API V3 events.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Device ? All devices don't respond the same way ^^
(so, did you try on latest devices ?)

By the way, you could take a look at http://www.jqtouch.com/ library ^^